# poLCA - Latent Class how to do the adjusted Lo-Mendell-Rubin (LMR) test with R

Tags: r, statistics

Good afternoon,
I am trying to perform Lo, Mendell and Rubin's (2001) adjusted test (LMR) in order to decide the optimal number of classes in LCA. I performed the command with poLCA, but I didn't find any command to perform it.
Is there someone that can help me?
Thank you very much!

Comment: "I performed the command with poLCA, but I didn't find any command to perform it." ?

Comment: I performed the latent class analysis with poLCA but I didn't find any command to do Lo, Mendell and Rubin test in order to decide the optimal number of classes. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of a (ad-hoc adjusted) LMR test comparing a LCA with 3 groups (alternative model) against 2 groups (baseline model).

```
# load packages/install if needed
library(poLCA)
library(tidyLPA)

data("election")

# Fit LCA with 2 classes (NULL model)
mod_null <- poLCA(formula = cbind(MORALG, CARESG, KNOWG) ~ 1, 
data = election, nclass = 2, verbose = F)  
# store values baseline model
n <- mod_null$Nobs #number of observations (should be equal in both models)
null_ll <- mod_null$llik #log-likelihood
null_param <- mod_null$npar # number of parameters
null_classes <- length(mod_null$P) # number of classes

# Fit LCA with 3 classes (ALTERNATIVE model)
mod_alt <- poLCA(formula = cbind(MORALG, CARESG, KNOWG) ~ 1, 
data = election, nclass = 3, verbose = F)  
# Store values alternative model
alt_ll <- mod_alt$llik #log-likelihood
alt_param <- mod_alt$npar # number of parameters
alt_classes <- length(mod_alt$P) # number of classes

# use calc_lrt from tidyLPA package
calc_lrt(n, null_ll, null_param, null_classes, alt_ll, alt_param, alt_classes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow really late to the game but as Im looking at similar things Ill leave for the next person.

The Lo-Mendell-Rubin test involves a transformation of the data and then a chi-sq test to determine if K classes is a better fit than K-1 classes... basically.

However there is reasonable research out there suggesting that a better measure of this is the bootstrap likelihood ratio.

The former is still in common use with MPlus users, the latter is far more common in LCA packages in R, e.g. mclust. Dunno about poLCA though...